# Php split SQL in separate queries

Tags: php, mysql, split, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to split SQL in separate queries... but still does not work

```
$string = 'CREATE TABLE `articles` (
`id` int(9) auto_increment,
`context` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8' COLLATE='utf8_general_ci';

INSERT INTO `articles` VALUES (1, "insert; row1;"),
(2, "update; row2;")';


preg_match_all("/([^;\"]*?(\".*?\")?)*?;\s*/U", $string, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```

Comment: Why split? Just write 2 variables with 2 queries?

Comment: Problem solved. Here is the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423260/split-sql-statements-in-php-on-semicolons-but-not-inside-quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split sql statements in php on semicolons (but not inside quotes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423260/split-sql-statements-in-php-on-semicolons-but-not-inside-quotes)

Answer (score 2):

Use explode:

```
$queries = explode(";\n", $string);
```

Or you can pre-filter the strings:

```
$strings = array();
function capture($match) {
    global $strings;
    $strings[] = $match[0];
    return '<<<' . count($strings) . '>>>';
}
function recopy($string) {
    global $strings;
    foreach($strings as $key => $value) {
        $string = str_replace('<<<' . $key . '>>>', $value, $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
$string = preg_replace_callback('#([\'"]).*(?<!\\\\)(?:\\\\\\\\)*\\1#isU', 'capture', $string);
$queries = array_map('recopy', explode(";", $string));
```

And escape ' with \' as says Rasmus.

Comment: Yes I have already edited that with ;\n and here is a second complete solution.

Comment: Code fixed, next time give the error message too when a code is failing. Plese less exclamation points.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75439362/12296332

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `explode(";",$string)` or find the ; position then `substr()`

Comment: I just see the problem: queries contain ; "insert; row1;" so it does not do the trick.

Comment: is this query always in this format which means one create table then the rest are insert?

Answer (score 1):

Another issue is that you are using the same ' for both php and the query, instead of wrapping the query in ' try using " instead.

Example:
CHARSET='utf8' <-- is using the same sign to tell sql that it's text, but you are allready using that sign to build your query